# How to run cd command/change the folder path from ruby script

Tags: ruby, bash

I am trying to run a command from ruby script. I got stuck in changing the folder path. Below is the command that I wrote. Can anyone let me know how to go ahead?

```
system("cd /home/user/Source/pxe/")
```

I want the terminal to point to the folder `pxe` when I run the ruby script. Is the code above correct? If not, can you let me know what the correct way is to call the `cd` command from ruby script?

Answer (score 7):

Do you want to change current directory for the script? Use [Dir.chdir](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Dir.html#method-c-chdir).

```
Dir.chdir('/home/user/Source/pxe')
```

Comment: `Dir.chdir` can also take a block, which is useful if you want to run only a section of code within a specific location. Within the block, you're in the location specified; once the block closes, everything is back as it was before.

Comment: Actually my requirement is: I should go to the folder path `/home/user/Source/pxe/` and then execute `git checkout` command on that folder through ruby script. How can I use `Dir.chdir` for this purpose ? 
Sorry I am new to programming and ruby, so I am getting little bit confused over this.

Comment: @Sergio. Thanks it works.
`Dir.chdir ("<folder path>") do
   <code goes here>
end` Thanks everyone for immediate response. :)

Comment: @threedaymonk. You are a life saver :) Thanks a lot for the tip.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [***`FileUtils#cd`***](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/fileutils/rdoc/FileUtils.html#method-c-cd) method.

> Changes the current directory to the directory dir.If this method is called with block, resumes to the old working directory after the block execution finished.

Example( I am on windows-7) :

```
require 'fileutils'

Dir.pwd # => "C:/Program Files/Notepad++"
FileUtils.cd("C:\\Users\\rakshiar\\Downloads")
Dir.pwd # => "C:/Users/rakshiar/Downloads"
```